# Flex/AS code for webcam

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, adobe

Can any one point me to a small piece of flex/AS code to test webcam and Microphone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The smallest amount of code you can use to create a web cam video feed is this:

```
var cam:Camera =  Camera.getCamera();
cam.setMode(640,480,30);
var video:Video = new Video(640, 480);
video.attachCamera(cam);
addChild(video);
```

Glancing over the docs will give you some additional properties and arguments that you can use to suit your needs.

**Update**
Here is a link to a working version of this code http://wonderfl.net/c/oGEY

Comment: i had gone through the docs addchild() event doesnt play the video

Comment: addChild() adds the video to the display list. If you put that piece of code into the constructor of some class that imports flash.media.* you'll see webcam video on the screen. Here is an example http://wonderfl.net/c/oGEY

Comment: Thanks for the wonderful demo.But wont this work on linux,Does this Os constraints??

Answer (score 2):

Adobe supplies examples in the documentation.  read [flash.media.Camera](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html) and [flash.media.Microphone](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html).  the examples you are looking for are under the [getCamera()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Camera.html#getCamera%28%29) and [getMicrophone()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Microphone.html#getMicrophone%28%29) public methods of the Camera and Microphone classes respectively.